Is it necessary to create a new groupId if a nested parent subproject is used in Maven?
Lets consider a Foo project has the following maven structure
Foo
- Core
   - Core API
   - Core IMPL
- Plugins
  - Plugin A
  - Plugin B

where Core and Plugins projects are parent maven projects that have two child modules.
Should I create a new groupId for them? For example, if we consider Core API module then its groupId should be com.company.foo or com.company.foo.core?

There are no technical restriction on group id.

Please don't close this question. This is a valid question, though maybe lacks a good formulation. I have already answered it.

I would go for the root level com.company.foo and the  Core part which should contain a pom file com.company.foo.core and the Core-API com.company.for.core.api etc..because the groupId represents a hierarchical structure (like the directory tree)....

No, this is not necessary.
Different people use different conventions for this.
